# Cloudformation error when deploying serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I am following a serverless tutorial and I am trying to send a notification every time an image is uploaded to the `s3 bucket`. I've created a `sendUploadNotifications` function under functions and instead of adding an event to the function I've set up the `"NotificationsConfiguration"` under the AttachmentsBucket, as well as created a new `sendUploadNotificationsPermissio`n Resource under resources.

But when I deploy the app I get the following error when I try to deploy my serverless app:

> Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource sendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction

The `Error` seems to stem from the way that I am referencing the FunctionName under the sendUploadNotificationsPermission resource.

I've tried different ways of referencing the function name, but to no avail. I still get the same error.

My `serverless.yml` file

```yaml
service: serverless-udagram2

frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'ap-southeast-1'}

  environment:
    GROUPS_TABLE: groups-${self:provider.stage}
    IMAGES_TABLE: images-${self:provider.stage}
    IMAGE_ID_INDEX: ImageIdIndex
    IMAGES_S3_BUCKET: branded-serverless-udagram-images-${self:provider.stage}
    SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION: 300

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:Query
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.GROUPS_TABLE}
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:Query
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_TABLE}
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_TABLE}/index/${self:provider.environment.IMAGE_ID_INDEX}
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:GetObject
      Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}/*


functions:

  getGroups:
    handler: src/lambda/http/getGroups.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: groups
          method: get
          cors: true

  createGroup:
    handler: src/lambda/http/createGroup.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: groups
          method: post
          cors: true
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(models/create-group-request.json)}

  getImages:
    handler: src/lambda/http/getImages.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: groups/{groupId}/images
          method: get
          cors: true

  getImage:
    handler: src/lambda/http/getImage.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: images/{imageId}
          method: get
          cors: true

  createImage:
    handler: src/lambda/http/createImage.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: groups/{groupId}/images
          method: post
          cors: true
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(models/create-image-request.json)}

  sendUploadNotifications:
    handler: src/lambda/s3/sendNotifications.handler


resources:

  Resources:

    # API gateway validates the request in accordance with json schemas that are identified in the function section under schema
    RequestBodyValidator:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
      Properties:
        Name: 'request-body-validator'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: true

    GroupsDynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.GROUPS_TABLE}

    ImagesDynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: groupId
              AttributeType: S
            - AttributeName: timestamp
              AttributeType: S
            - AttributeName: imageId
              AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: groupId
            KeyType: HASH #partition key
          - AttributeName: timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE #sort key
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.IMAGE_ID_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: imageId
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_TABLE}

    #    Bucket for file uploads
    AttachmentsBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}
          NotificationConfiguration: # Sends notification when image has been uploaded
            LambdaConfigurations: #
              - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
                Function: !GetAtt sendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction.Arn
          CorsConfiguration:
            CorsRules:
              -
                AllowedOrigins:
                  - "*"
                AllowedHeaders:
                  - "*"
                AllowedMethods:
                  - 'GET'
                  - 'PUT'
                  - 'POST'
                  - 'DELETE'
                  - 'HEAD'
                MaxAge: 3000

    sendUploadNotificationsPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: !GetAtt sendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction.Arn
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
        SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId #!Ref
        SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}

    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: MyPolicy
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action: 's3:GetObject'
              Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}/*'
        Bucket:
          Ref: AttachmentsBucket
```

I've tried changing the name of the function in both the `sendUploadNotificationsPermission` and the `AttachmentsBucket` by appending LamdaFunction to the end of the function name, but still getting the same error.

Any help with this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference something which doesn't exist in the template at in the `CloudFormation` section `Resource`.

> sendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction

In case you want to reference any of the function you have defined named

> sendUploadNotifications

you need to construct the ARN inside the `Resources` section.

To generate Logical ID for CloudFormation, the plugin transform the specified name in serverless.yml based on the following scheme.

```
Transform a leading character into uppercase
Transform - into Dash
Transform _ into Underscore
```

> SendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction in your case.

There are now two ways:

1. You reference this inside `Resource` section of the template:

```yaml
    sendUploadNotificationsPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: !GetAtt SendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction.Arn
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
        SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId #!Ref
        SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}
```

2. You construct the ARN using [Fn::Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html).

```yaml
    sendUploadNotificationsPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: !Join [":", ['arn:aws:lambda', !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref AWS::AccountId, '${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-sendUploadNotifications']]
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
        SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId #!Ref
        SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}
```

Comment: Thanx, for the reply. It set me on the path to the solution.

Comment: @CharlSwart glad it helped!! can you mark this question as solved if it is possible?. That helps the community and anyone who stumble upon this quetstion.

Comment: Thanks
The one thing I would add that dashes '-' and underscores '_' will be replaced by strings "Dash" and "Underscore" accordingly.
So my_lambda-func becomes MyUnderscorelambdaDashfuncLambdaFunction

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The 'references undefined resource error' was caused by the fact that after the serverless.yml file compiles it capitalizes the function name.

sendUploadNotifications becomes SendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction

changed:

```
FunctionName: !Ref sendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction
```

to:

```
FunctionName: !Ref SendUploadNotificationsLambdaFunction
```

It now deploys without an issue.